# PHP script on Amazon EC2 possibly cached

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I've got a PHP script on an Amazon EC2 instance. I changed a couple things in it, but the output is the same when I load it in my browser. Does Amazon have some sort of caching in place? I know the East zone was down today, but my instance is running fine now. I've ruled out client-side caching already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our ec2 instances this sort of thing happens in 2 scenarios:

1) a bug in our deployment ( for example, puppet or another deploy tool did something funny) or

2) git : a branch was not pushed to head, but the server redeploy happend.

Unless you are using a caching system which you know of, there is no reason to think that ec2 is caching things under the hood - ec2 is controlled and configured quite directly .